# call all functions to submit form

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and am looking on how to validate my form on button click, but my script keeps jumping to the first function validate Name an stays highlighted, I don't know what to put in the clear all function so it jumps to the next non validated item

```
function validate_form(form)
{
    var complete=false;

    if(complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);
    }
    if(complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkaddress(form.address.value);
    }
    if(complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkaddress(form.address.value);
    }

    if (complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkphone(form.phone.value);
    }
    if (complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkEmail(email.phone.value);
    }
}

function clear_all()
{
    document.getElementById('usernamehint').style.visibility= 'hidden';
    document.basicform.username.style.backgroundColor='white';
    document.getElementById("countryhint").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    document.basicform.country.style.backgroundColor='white';
    document.getElementById("").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    document.basicformm.address.style.backgroundColor='white';
    document.getElementById("").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    document.basicform.phone.style.backgroundColor='white';
    document.getElementById("").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    document.basicform.email.style.backgroundColor='white';
}

function checkUsernameForLength(whatYouTyped)
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 2) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
        return true;
    } else {
        fieldset.className = "";
        return false;
    }
}

function checkEmail(whatYouTyped) 
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(txt)) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    } else {
        fieldset.className = "";
    }
}



function checkaddress(whatYouTyped)
 {
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 3 && txt.length <10) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    }
     else {
        fieldset.className = "";
    }
}



function checkphone(whatYouTyped)
 {
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
 if ( /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/.test(txt)) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    }
 else
 {
        fieldset.className = "";
    }
}



function addLoadEvent(func) 
{
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') 
{
    window.onload = func;
  }
 else
 {
    window.onload = function()
 {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}


function prepareInputsForHints() 
{
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
{
    inputs[i].onfocus = function () 
{
      this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
    }
    inputs[i].onblur = function () 
{
      this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Strongly suggest using JQuery validate:   http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: `document.getElementById("")` why empty string? what do you mean by that? You can't read/write style of something that returns `null`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` - that's why browser stops while executing `clear_all();`

Comment: document.getElementById("") is because i'm not sure what to put in

Comment: the id of an element that you want to hide

Comment: ye i tried call "hint" but it did not work it stayed at the first 1 "name"

Comment: anyway, none of your validation functions returns `true` or `false`, so line like this: `complete = checkaddress(form.address.value);` doesn't make any sense. You have to use `return` within your function, like: `validate(any_var){ if(any_var == "ok") return true; else return false; }`

Comment: There's a site ( www.jsfiddle.net ), where you can put html/JavaScript/CSS and make link to it, then all can see and run it. Please, make one and I'll improve your code and make comments what was wrong.

Comment: Martin, please indent your code by 4 spaces using the code `{}` button, so it will be properly formatted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkUsernameForLength(name, callback) {
    if (error) {
        return [null, error];
    }
    return [name, null]
}
var series = function(funcs, success, error) {
    var results = errors = [];
    for (var i in funcs) {
        var result = funcs[i]();
        results.push(result[0]);
        errors.push(result[1]);
        if (result[1]) {
            return error(results, errors);
        }
    }
    return success(results);
}
series([
    function() {
        return checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);
    }
], function(results) {
    form.submit();
}, function(results, errors) {
    alert(errors.join("\n"));
});
```

series call each validation function and stop execution if some error passed.
Than calls errors or success function if is or not errors.

PS. It's right way to learn javascript. You shouldn't use any sugars like jQuery if you want to know javascript well.

Comment: i only started learn 2 months ago so i'm very slow at it , should i just copy above to include all my functions , i'm stuck here the last 2 days :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't carefully review your code. I wrote another answer with definition of issue. The code above you may use after you will improve your js skills :)

Comment: +1 for not recommending jQuery, -1 for using a `for … in` loop to iterate over an array; [never do that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description).

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend the following methodology:

You have a list of validator functions, of the form

```
{ // map of ids : validators
    name: function(formElement) {..., return 'Cannot be all lowercase' or return 'Other error'}, 
    email: function(formElement) {...}, 
    ...
}
```

Each validator function returns an error message, or nothing (undefined) if there was no problem.

Then using $.each over id:validator pairs, you do something like (code is probably buggy):

```
$(id).bind(
    'change', //?
    function () {
        // Called when user changes form elements, you can use an alert, or better
        // something not annoying like...
        $(id).css({'background-color':'yellow'})
        $(id+'-error').get(0).innerHtml = validator(id);
    }
)
```

This method has the advantage that it the user will see all errors at once, rather than one-at-a-time.

Alternatively, every time the user hits submit, you then do something like a $.map or $.each to run all the validator functions, and complain appropriately.

Also note that you cannot depend on client-side code to validate your forms, since it is trivial for a user or hacker to disable or ignore your validation code and send whatever values they'd like to your server. However, client-side validation code is very useful for a smooth and responsive user experience.

Comment: Im sorry thats a bit advanced for me i am a 1st year soft dev student and am doing JavaScript as an extra but am struggling ,my validation works but i cant get it to drop through the form

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and got the main issue of your code:
Here is a part of validation:

```
    complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);
}
if(complete)

……

function checkUsernameForLength(whatYouTyped) {
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 2) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    }
    else {
        fieldset.className = "fail";
    }
}
```

The issue is that checkUsernameForLength doesn't return the value, so complete doesn't have value.
You should change your function code to:

```
function checkUsernameForLength(whatYouTyped) {
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 2) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
        return true;
    } else {
        fieldset.className = "fail";
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case

```
complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);
```

Will have true or false value if no errors or some error. And it will stop execution of validation

Comment: Thanks a million , will i have to change all my other functions to look like above , i still have the problem with the  clear_all(); what ID should i call  all my fieldset are the same                            <fieldset> 
  <label for="username">Name:</label> 
  <input type="text"id="username" onkeyup="checkUsernameForLength(this);" /> 
  <span class="hint">This Field Must Not Be Left Blank !</span> 
  </fieldset>

Comment: `<span class="hint" id="usernamehint">` and `document.getElementById('usernamehint').style.visibility= 'hidden';`

Comment: i change these things but no joy i will edit the above question             Thanks for all the help :)